# Excel Imports way more rows than expected

Tags: excel, vb.net, import

with my code below I'm importing an excel file that contains 5 worksheets, but I'm only wanting data from 3 of them. I'm getting about 7 times as many rows as expected. How do I ensure I only get populated rows from each sheet? no dupes.

```
  Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conn").ToString
    Dim excelConnString As String = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath(excelFile) & "; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml; HDR=Yes""")
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(excelConnString)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    conn.Open()
    Dim dtSheet As DataTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

    For Each sheet As System.Data.DataRow In dtSheet.Rows

        Dim sheetName As String = sheet("table_name").ToString()
        If sheetName = "UT$" Or sheetName = "XRAY$" Or sheetName = "FLANGE$" Then
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from [" & sheetName & "] WHERE [Drawing] Is Not NULL"
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            Dim myImportFinding As New ImportFinding

            For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1

                If dt.Rows(i)("Platform") Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(dt.Rows(i)("Platform")) Then
                    myImportFinding.PLATFORM = ""
                Else
                    myImportFinding.PLATFORM = dt.Rows(i)("Platform")
                End If
```

Comment: Sorry, normally do C# forgot I was doing vb. oops thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: missing a whole bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there was a whole lot of code missing, but the important parts are there. I decided to refactor and have it working now. Each time I looped through it inserted all the rows from the three worksheets. I decided to move the actual import out into a new method and started off with a fresh data table, command and data adapter for each workbook. Seems to work fine now.